How to get the value of specific node in XSLT
Here's what my data looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <key>book/item=1,book/author=PhilipS</key>
    <subject>OK</subject>
    <units>UPSERTED</units>
  </data>
</root>

I want to get the author name:
Philips

Choose one version of xslt

oopss! got it sorry

Something like this:
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="root/data/key"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lookupString" select="'book/author='"/>
    <options>
      <option using="substring-after">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($key,$lookupString)"/>
      </option>
      <option using="tokenize">
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($key,'=')[last()]"/>
      </option>
      <option using="combination">
        <!-- Safest if order of values could change -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(tokenize($key,',')[starts-with(.,$lookupString)],$lookupString)"/>
      </option>
    </options>
  </xsl:template> 



Thank you so much!!! I'm going to use the third option. :)
